# Discover if there is a missing close tag in HTML while using Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome

Is there a way to use Google Chrome to discover if the HTML is missing any closing tags?

I need do this on the `localhost` so an external HTML validator won't work.

Comment: Use the Developer console (F12), but I doubt it will be of much help in this case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the official HTML validator from the W3C. There is an option for direct input, simply copy/paste your html markup into the formfield.

http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Perhaps there is also a plugin for your favorite IDE which can validate html.

Answer (score 12):

Along with the W3C HTML validator already mentioned, you can also upload local files.

http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload

There is also the microsoft visual studio mark up validation for web-forms:

> When you edit markup in the Visual Studio Web designer (for Web Forms pages, in Source view), the editor checks that the markup is valid. Markup validation works like the spelling checker in a word-processing program. The editor examines the markup and adds wavy red lines under the elements or attributes that are not valid.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f940516c.aspx

There are also Text Editors like Dreamweaver which will check your code for errors.

Actually Notepad ++ is also good for checking various language formats.